# Is there an alternative to Applocker in Windows 7 Professional that is built into the operating system?

Tags: windows-7, applocker

I tried to configure Applocker to block a particular executable or allow only a certain group to access it, but as far as I can tell it is not supported in Windows 7 Professional even though policy terms exists for it.

I see the error message: appidsvc.dll: AppLocker component not available on this SKU.

From this link, it does not look as though the particular feature I need is available in Windows 7:
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee424382.aspx

I appreciate that third party products may exist but would rather use a built in feature. I have looked into software restriction policies but that feature seems to have been deprecated by Microsoft.

Comment: You are 100% correct, it can be configured, but it cannot be enforced.  There are indeed alternatives to Applocker, what those are, will require research on your part to determine which alternative fits your needs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an **alternate** solution.

You can encrypt executable files using **Windows EFS** (Encrypting File System) feature so that others cannot use your file.

The EFS feature of Windows encrypts the file with your password. You don't need to remember any separate passwords to access your files. Also, if you want to give access to another user, you can install your certificate on their user and so, even they can start using it.

**Note :** You can't use this feature on Windows 7 Starter, Windows 7 Home Basic, and Windows 7 Home Premium.

You can encrypt a file using by going to Properties --> General --> Advanced --> Encrypt.

[image: Encrypt file or folder]

**To create a backup of the certificate :**

1. Open Certificate Manager by clicking the Start button Picture of the Start button, typing **certmgr.msc** into the search box, and then pressing Enter.‌ Administrator permission required If you're prompted for an administrator password or confirmation, type the password or provide confirmation.
2. In the left pane, double-click **Personal**.
3. Click **Certificates**.
4. In the main pane, click the certificate that lists **Encrypting File System** under **Intended Purposes**. (You might need to scroll to the right to see this.)
5. If there is more than one EFS certificate, you should back up all of them.
6. Click the **Action** menu, point to **All Tasks**, and then click **Export**.
7. In the Certificate Export wizard, click **Next**, click **Yes, export the private key**, and then click **Next**.
8. Click **Personal Information Exchange**, and then click **Next**.
9. Type the password you want to use, confirm it, and then click **Next**. The export process will create a file to store the certificate.
10. Type a name for the file and the location (include the whole path) or click **Browse**, navigate to a location, type a file name, and then click **Save**.
11. Click **Next**, and then click **Finish**.

**To install the certificate :**

1. Double-Click the certificate you want to install
2. Click **Next**, and then enter the password you used to protect the certificate and then click **Next**.
3. Click **Automatically select the certificate store based on the type of certificate** and then click **Next**
4. Click **Finish** and the import of the certificate will be successful.
5. **Restart** your computer for the changes come in effect. *(optional)*

Comment: How do you install the certificate?, your answer is incomplete.

Comment: @Moab I included all steps, now remove `-1` **if** you are the one who awarded me that.

Comment: @Private Thanks private. If I could vote up then I would.

Comment: Oh yeah, those are the answers we like!

Comment: @Moab Indeed we do! Thanks for encouraging the user to improve their answer.