# How do I recover Windows EFS keys

Tags: windows-10, disk-encryption, acronis-trueimage, efs

Long before my hard drive crashed I backed it up using Acronis TrueImage 2010, a full partition backup of Windows 7 Professional 64bits.

Oddly enough, the C OS partition is the placed as the second partition right after D and Acronis fails to restore from the backup (it restores but the restore is not bootable).

I can access the content of the backup using Acronis. Most of the files are encrypted using EFS and are inaccessible.

How can I restore the EFS private key (I know the username password) or at least make the Acronis restore bootable in a way I could read the encrypted files?

Comment: The only way to get the EFS key is to boot up the drive and [backup the key](http://superuser.com/a/1064631/573485). Knowing the username and password doesn't make a difference.

Comment: any idea how to make the drive bootable and why after its restoration it won't boot ?

Comment: You can try this : Install the same version of windows with another OS, i.e.,2 operating systems will be running on your computer. Then copy all the files from the restore into the partition where the same version of Windows is installed. You will have to overwrite all files. You can probably do this only with your 2nd OS. After that, boot up and recover your EFS key. You could also use a live disc instead of installing a 2nd OS. You will have to be a techie to get this done. This works in theory and has been done. However, I cannot be 100% sure if you'll be successful.