# how to decrypt an encrypted file from a old account

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, efs, decrypt

So awhile back I was just testing out the encryption thing to just see what all it did and how it works etc. Little did I know I forgot to decrypt them before I formatted disk. I do still have all the files on another drive which I copied over, all there, but they are all still encrypted. Is there any possible way I can decrypt these or open these files again?

*I apologize. I am on windows 10 now but I believe the files were from windows 7 through EFS

Comment: If you do not have the decryption key, and it sounds like you don't, then it will not be possible to recover the original files.  This assumes properly implemented encryption which is very common today.

Comment: Would I be able to get the decryption key from the old hard drive? Like through a recovery program at all?

Comment: “Would I be able to get the decryption key from the old hard drive?” - You would have to boot into the OS to do that.  If you didn’t export the key consider the files lost

Answer (score 0):

> **Would I be able to get the [EFS] decryption key from the old hard drive? Like through a recovery program at all?**

It is probably a long shot but may be possible.

---

See [encrypted file system recovery](http://www.beginningtoseethelight.org/efsrecovery/index.htm)

> how to import users encrypted file system (efs) keys from an old offline profile into a new system in order to gain authorized access to previously inaccessible encrypted data.

---

See also

- [How do I recover Windows EFS keys](https://superuser.com/q/1120835/52492)
- [Recover EFS encrypted folder after wiping system partition](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/7990/recover-efs-encrypted-folder-after-wiping-system-partition)

---

There are companies that sell products that claim to be able to help with this. [Example](https://www.elcomsoft.co.uk/aefsdr.html).

> - Recover encrypted files if the system partition was formatted
> - Search for encryption keys with low-level disk scan

---

You should probably take all the disks offline, make backups of the disks (e.g. disk images transferred to new disks) and work on copies of the disks, keeping the old disks locked away and out of use.

Comment: He formatted the disk after copying the encrypted files elsewhere ...

Comment: @DavidPostil, but, as you know, typical formatting doesn't overwrite file contents. Parts of the contents of files such as the user profile / registry data *may* still be recoverable. AIUI if you have the encryption certificates and the encrypted files you can decrypt without first having to exactly reinstate *all* of the original drive state.

Comment: So all I really need is the encryption certificates more or less?

Comment: also would you recommend the advanced efs data recovery or no? is it really worth the 300 bucks???

Comment: @Steve I can't recommend it because I have not used it (I make multiple backups and check readability of backups). Whether it is worth $300 depends on your personal valuation of your files and your assessment of the chances of success. If you send the disks to a recovery specialist it will cost thousands, also with no guarantees of success. I find it cheaper to buy USB hard disks, USB flash drives and fireproof boxes and make and test multiple local and remote backups than to rely on post-disaster recovery.